# Digikam not starting after update: Failed to update the database schema from version 12 to version 13

Tags: digikam

I've got Digikam running on Archlinux, with my photo database stored in MariaDB. This worked fine, until a recent upgrade. When I try to open Digikam, it returns:

> Failed to update the database schema from version 12 to version 13.
> Please read the error messages printed on the console and report this
> error as a bug at bugs.kde.org.

When opening it from the console, these messages are shown:

> digikam.coredb: Core database: cannot process schema initialization
> QThreadStorage: Thread 0x7f77f1091560 exited after QThreadStorage 13
> destroyed

Answer (score 1):

There is a dbconfig.xml file, located in my case at:

> /usr/share/digikam/database/dbconfig.xml

This file contains the SQL commands that need to be run. In this case I isolated the following code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_index_if_not_exists;

CREATE PROCEDURE create_index_if_not_exists(table_name_vc varchar(50), index_name_vc varchar(50), field_list_vc varchar(1024))
BEGIN

set @Index_cnt = (
    SELECT COUNT(1) cnt
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE CONVERT(DATABASE() USING latin1) = CONVERT(TABLE_SCHEMA USING latin1)
      AND CONVERT(table_name USING latin1) = CONVERT(table_name_vc USING latin1)
      AND CONVERT(index_name USING latin1) = CONVERT(index_name_vc USING latin1)
);

IF IFNULL(@Index_cnt, 0) = 0 THEN
    set @index_sql = CONCAT(
        CONVERT( 'ALTER TABLE ' USING latin1),
        CONVERT( table_name_vc USING latin1),
        CONVERT( ' ADD INDEX ' USING latin1),
        CONVERT( index_name_vc USING latin1),
        CONVERT( '(' USING latin1),
        CONVERT( field_list_vc USING latin1),
        CONVERT( ');' USING latin1)
    );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @index_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
                    END;

CALL create_index_if_not_exists('TagsTree','tagstree_id_index','id');

CALL create_index_if_not_exists('TagsTree','tagstree_pid_index','pid');

ALTER TABLE UniqueHashes CHANGE uniqueHash uniqueHash VARCHAR(128);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CustomIdentifiers
                    (identifier LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8,
                    thumbId INTEGER,
                    UNIQUE(identifier(333)));

CALL create_index_if_not_exists('CustomIdentifiers','id_customIdentifiers','thumbId');

ALTER TABLE Settings RENAME ThumbSettings;

ALTER TABLE ThumbSettings
                    MODIFY COLUMN keyword VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
                    MODIFY COLUMN value LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE ThumbSettings ENGINE InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Thumbnails ENGINE InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE UniqueHashes ENGINE InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE FilePaths MODIFY COLUMN path VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE FilePaths ENGINE InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE CustomIdentifiers MODIFY COLUMN identifier VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE CustomIdentifiers ENGINE InnoDB;

                ALTER TABLE UniqueHashes
                    ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueHashes_Thumbnails FOREIGN KEY (thumbId) REFERENCES Thumbnails (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

                ALTER TABLE FilePaths
                    ADD CONSTRAINT FilePaths_Thumbnails FOREIGN KEY (thumbId) REFERENCES Thumbnails (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

                ALTER TABLE CustomIdentifiers
                    ADD CONSTRAINT CustomIdentifiers_Thumbnails FOREIGN KEY (thumbId) REFERENCES Thumbnails (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

OPTIMIZE TABLE Albums, Images, ImageInformation, ImageMetadata, VideoMetadata, ImagePositions, ImageComments, ImageCopyright, ImageProperties, ImageHistory, ImageRelations, Tags, ImageTags, ImageTagProperties;
OPTIMIZE TABLE Thumbnails, UniqueHashes, FilePaths, CustomIdentifiers;
OPTIMIZE TABLE Identities, IdentityAttributes;
OPTIMIZE TABLE ImageSimilarity, ImageHaarMatrix, SimilaritySettings;
CHECK TABLE Albums, Images, ImageInformation, ImageMetadata, VideoMetadata, ImagePositions, ImageComments, ImageCopyright, ImageProperties, ImageHistory, ImageRelations, Tags, ImageTags, ImageTagProperties;
CHECK TABLE Thumbnails, UniqueHashes, FilePaths, CustomIdentifiers;
CHECK TABLE Identities, IdentityAttributes;
CHECK TABLE ImageSimilarity, ImageHaarMatrix, SimilaritySettings;
```

And I ran this directly on the database holding my pictures. There were a few errors, but after running this digikam started fine and everything seems in order.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately can't comment on @user74934's answer, however I attempted to run his code and got the error `ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted` for mariadb.

If anyone encounters this problem, I managed to solve it with inspiration from this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224954). I ran the command: `mariadb-upgrade --socket=mysql.socket digikam` in order to fix my instance.